# Unable to display data in angular material table

Tags: angular, material-design

Using angular material design data table, I need to fetch data from an REST API and display the response in the table.

But having issue in displaying the data in the table.

**Modal.ts**

```
export interface ReleaseModal {
    results: [{
        id: number;
        title: string;
    }]
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
  getReleaseNotes(): Observable<ReleaseModal[]> {
      return this.http.get<ReleaseModal[]>(this.url);
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
export class ReleasesComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
  title = 'Release notes';
  displayedColumns = ['releasenotes'];
  dataSource;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor ( private releaseNotes: ReleaseService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.releaseNotes.getReleaseNotes()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="releasenotes">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Release Notes </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.results.title}}% </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

When I console log the `data`, I could see the results but not sure why it is not displaying in the table. Please help

Below is the sample response, which I get from the API call

```
{
"results": [
{
"id": "203901655",
"title": "Test Page",
},
....
}
```

Comment: Do  you attach the `[dataSource]="dataSource"` to mat-table? If yes, are you getting any error on console window?

Comment: I'm getting this `TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined`. i think the issue might be in the Modal.ts or data mapping, i don't know whether I've done the mapping properly or not

Comment: Pls add all your code related to mat-table in question.

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ngOnInit` as below, should fix it:

```
dispalyedColumns=['title']
ngOnInit() {
    this.releaseNotes.getReleaseNotes()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.results);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Remove the lines in `ngAfterViewInit`. The issue is since `ngAfterViewInit` gets called before you get data from service and `dataSource` is still undefined.

HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="title">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Release Notes </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.title}}% </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
</mat-row>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `TypeError: data.slice is not a function`

Comment: @ArunKumar seems `data` isn't an array, `data.results` is an array. See my edit.

Comment: Yes its an object, with array inside it, Sample response is in my question

Comment: Check my edit in my answer `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.results);`

Comment: I get this error `[ts] Property 'results' does not exist on type 'ReleaseModal[]'.
`

Comment: `ReleaseModal[]` is an array? so actually you getting array of arrays. I think you should get `ReleaseModal` not an array. Pls check.

Comment: I tried removing the array like this  from service file `  getReleaseNotes(): Observable<ReleaseModal> {
      return this.http.get<ReleaseModal>(this.url);
  }` still I'm getting this `[ts] Property 'results' does not exist on type 'ReleaseModal'.
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181957/discussion-between-user3250-and-arun-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
export class ReleasesComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
  title = 'Release notes';
  displayedColumns = ['releasenotes'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ReleaseModal>();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor ( private releaseNotes: ReleaseService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.releaseNotes.getReleaseNotes()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```